# How to remove thousand separator in a list of tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a master_list which contains a list of lists, I'm trying to turn it into a list of tuples that only contains line[3]: the numbers of games played, and line[0]: the players' names. The list will be sorted on games played (highest to lowest) and only the top ten are
returned, i.e. the list contains ten tuples in decreasing, sorted order. 
**And I must  remove the comma and convert to an integer before sorting**

The output of my code is correct except the thousand separators are still there. This is my code:

```
def games_played(master_list):
container2 = []
for line in master_list:
    try:
        int(line[3])
        continue
    except ValueError:
        for i in line[3]:
            i = i.replace(",", "")
            continue
    container2.append(((line[3]), line[0]))
container2.sort(reverse = True)
container2 = container2[:10]
print(container2)
```

and this is my output:

```
[
 ('1,767', 'Gordie Howe'),
 ('1,756', 'Mark Messier'),
 ('1,733', 'Jaromir Jagr'),
 ('1,731', 'Ron Francis'),
 ('1,514', 'Steve Yzerman'),
 ('1,487', 'Wayne Gretzky'),
 ('1,451', 'Teemu Selanne'),
 ('1,409', 'Paul Coffey'),
 ('1,396', 'Stan Mikita'),
 ('1,378', 'Joe Sakic')
]
```

Comment: your `for` loop with `replace` doesn't have any effect. It has no meaning to assign to `i` because it is the loop variable. Also the line `int(line[3])` doesn't do nothing. Just do `container2.append(((int(line[3].replace(',', '')), line[0]))` without the whole `try/except`

Comment: The indentation of your code looks broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the line (after the last assignment to container2):

```
container2 = list(map(lambda x: (int(x[0].replace(',','')),x[1]),container2))
```

Comment: What's the point of using `list()`, `map()` and a `lambda`, over a list comprehension?